# To make a div float between 2 divs

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

How to make a div float between two divs?
[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zItat.png)

Could this be extended to work in different screen sizes?
So that no absolute referencing is used.

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) might help you.

Comment: Thanks, but am not trying to fix a bug by posting the code. In this question, if I post the code others would just try to correct it instead of helping me with the concepts that I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.contener{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.bloc_1,
.bloc_2,
.bloc_3{
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(33.33% - 5px);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done in so many way but there somes usefull links and code :

```
.contener{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.bloc_1,
.bloc_2,
.bloc_3{
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(33.33% - 5px);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

-[inline-block](https://codepen.io/FabienGreard/pen/jPBWPG)

-[flexbox](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/)

-[grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)